# Visual Studio Configuration Properties

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Why are certain properties not dependent on the current configuration?

For example, why can't I specify a different startup project based on the current configuration?

Comment: You need to ask it on connect.microsoft.com!

Comment: You are asking a new feature, Microsoft hast to answer this question. Your question doesn't say what is your problem, state your problem somebody may help you.

Answer (score 4):

Configuration is meant to be all about how your project is built: x86 or amd64, ret or debug, etc ...  The Visual Studio UI is geared around this experience and hence only presents the ability to configure build related tasks.

This is not to say that actions like `StartAction` can't be tied to configuration: they actually can.  The project file format, at least for C#, VB.Net and F#, is just an MSBuild file.  You can hand edit it to bind certain items to configuration properties

For example:

```
<StartProgram Condition="$(pick your msbuild prop)">Some\Path\app.exe</StartProgram>
```

Answer (score 0):

While this may make sense to YOUR specific needs, the actual build configurations are tied to different Project based values (Debug flags, output folder, Target platform, etc).

The Startup Project is defined per Solution, so this makes sense to me that it is not tied to any specific build configuration.

Raise this on Microsoft Connect. While it is not assured that your issue will be solved, they are very responsive and willing to assist very quickly.