# Different startup projects for different configurations

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way of having different projects as startup projects for different configurations?
as far as I can see visual studio doeswnt let you pick a configuration when choosing a startup project.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Configuration Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695895/visual-studio-configuration-properties)

Answer (score 3):

Start up project is a common property across all configurations, so you can not make it configuration specific.